# Subprocess reacts differently on SIGINT signals

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess

b.py

```
import subprocess
f = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'a.py'])
time.sleep(3000)
```

a.py

```
import time
time.sleep(1000)
```

Run python b.py, Press CTRL+C, both processes will terminate.

However send the signal SIGINT to the parent process b.py, kill -2 xxxx, but the child process a.py remains.

Comment: What makes you think a CTRL-C is handled as a SIGINT?

Comment: typo. SIGINT. I'm talking about signal 2 anyway

Comment: Same question, what makes you think CTRL-C is a simple SIGINT? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Linux. Every piece of information I find on Internet tells me CTRL+C equals to SIGINT.

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is similar to `os.killpg(xxxx, signal.SIGTERM)` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-C` at your terminal typically sends `SIGINT` to **all processes in the foreground process group**. Both your parent and your child process are in this process group.

For a more detailed explanation, see for example [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) or the more technical version by Kirk McKusick at [Process Groups and Sessions](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366888&seqNum=8)

If you just kill the parent process, the child is *parentless* and thus gets reparented to PID 1 (init). You can see this too, in the output of `ps`. Since your subprocess never receives a signal, it simply continues running.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I need. I don't care about an orphan process, my initial purpose was to keep it running even if the parent process dies. Then the ctrl+c issue came to bother me. Looks like I have to trap those signals in the foreground process.

Comment: I think what you want is called *daemonizing* the child. There's actually a PEP for that: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/

Comment: This document is too complicated for me to understand. Can I just use subprocess.Popen to run a new process? Of course,  set the preexec_fn parameter to os.setsid(), in order to make the child process disassociate from parent process group.

Comment: I'd suggest using package `python-daemon` for those purposes.